# How does the following hit points formula change the balance?

Tags: dnd-5e, hit-points

Our DM is usually harsh, and to compensate, he offers to change the hp formula that we gain each level. He suggests that for each level we get the maximum between a roll and the usual average HP, plus the CON modifier.

So if my new hit dice is 8, I roll and either take it or the average of 5, my choice. If I roll 2, I'll get 5 + CON mod HP, and if I roll 7, I get 7 + CON mod HP.

How unbalanced is this method? Given that he often makes us lose HP for things as simple as failing to break a door open, or taking damage on a roll of 1.

Comment: When you ask about change of balance, is there a specific concern you have?

Comment: @RisingZan Please don't answer in comments (math light or heavy), [we try not to do that here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533).

Comment: @Ifusaso Experience using this system is a strong basis for an answer. You should post it as one, however it is too close to an answer to remain as a comment.

Comment: That's fair, I'm not sure its enough to post as an answer but I'll consider it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Subtle But Powerful

I am not going to venture a hard opinion on whether this is overpowered; we don't know enough about how "tough" your GM is, and I'm not sure it's possible to convey anyway.

Also, [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/205878/18269) is computationally correct, but interpretationally incorrect, and significantly understates the benefit of this method:

- Since we are considering the effect over multiple levels, rounding is not appropriate.  The average value of the sum of 10 sequential unmodified rolls of a d12 is not 70 (due to rounding) it is 65. Using the new method, the average sum is not 80 (due to rounding) it is 82.5.  So the difference for the averages is not 10, it is actually 17.5.
- Average is not the end-all and be-all, however.  This improved method greatly reduces the standard deviation of the individual rolls.  This is difficult to interpret, due to the point I will raise next, but in a nutshell small standard deviations imply a tighter grouping of values, avoiding both highs and lows.
- Typically, when we try to intuit our way through statistics and probabilities, we think of the distributions as symmetric-- high value excursions being just as likely as low value excursions.  This method fundamentally changes that assumption, as its distribution is not even close to symmetric.  Rather, it is single sided.  That's where the standard deviation reduction comes from-- it is a direct result of the lack of symmetry.

A better way to think about it is by looking at the following chart, summarizing the minima, averages, and maxima of ten dice rolls for each method.  You can clearly see that, while the maxima are not affected at all (similar to a typical "advantage" roll from 5e), the minima are affected to a huge degree and the averages are also affected a great deal.

In fact, the **minimum roll** of the new method is always greater than the **average roll** of the typical method!

This strikes me as a massive benefit accruing over time.
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline   & Min (standard) & Avg (standard) & Max (standard) & Min (new) & Avg (new) & Max (new) \\ \hline 10 d4s & 10 & 25 & 40 & 30 & 32.5 & 40 \\ \hline 10 d6s & 10 & 35 & 60 &  40 & 45 & 60 \\ \hline 10 d8s & 10 & 45 & 80 & 50 & 57.5 & 80 \\ \hline 10 d10s & 10 & 55 & 100 &  60 & 70 & 100 \\ \hline 10 d12s & 10 & 65 & 120 &  70 & 82.5 & 120 \\ \hline  \end{array}

Comment: Good catch, I should know about propagation of errors!

Comment: @Eddymage happens to the best of us!  You made such a persuasive case I actually upvoted it and then five minutes later thought, "Hey, waitaminute....!"

Comment: Yeah, I saw the vote change! :-D I focused too much on the compact formula for the expected value and I did not considered that even 0.25 HPs could do a difference...

Comment: the advantages do not accrue over time, the other rolls are likely to be at the regular "average" value.  This is no more complicated a calculation than Great Weapon Fighting

Comment: @TigerGuy Yes, they do accumulate.  In addition to pencil and paper calculations, I also wrote a python script just to be sure.

Comment: @Novak please show us how results diverge from an average.

Comment: @Novak I already done the numerical simulation (in MatLab), and they confirm your table. It is not surprising, given the linearity of the expectation...

Comment: Set up a chatroom if you want, @TigerGuy.  I don't know what mistake you're making, but you are definitely making one.

Comment: One thing I dislike is that you compare this method to the roll method and not to the take average method which is canon. Both should be taken into account since anyone can choose between the two.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: The rounded-up average (e.g. 4 on a d6) from the PHB gives 0.5HP more per level than flat dice (without discarding ones or anything), for any size of hit die.  Since this table is for 10th level, the take-average method will be 5 HP higher than the dice average for each size of hit die.  e.g. for 10d8, 50 HP (PHB average) vs. 57.5 HP (new method).  Or for barbarian, 70 vs. 82.5.

Comment: @PeterCordes I know, it's just that the answer is missing that bit (even though I accepted it). Also, it's for 11th level, since canon you get the full hit dice at level 1, and only start rolling or taking average from level 2 onwards.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Hah-- yes, you caught my dodge.  I was too lazy to work out the initial level with a full hit die.  I carefully worded the response to be just consecutive die rolls.

Answer (score 7):

#### The gain seems poor: 1 HP per level on average.

---

*Note: this answer contains the correct computation, but a wrong interpretation of the results (see [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/205880/63061) for the correct one). I leave this one here for the mathematical details, in case anyone is interested in them.*

---

Considering the various types of Hit Dice, we have the following differences (in brackets the true expected values):

- d6:  the average shifts from 4(3.5) to 5(4.5)
- d8:  the average shifts from 5(4.5) to 6(5.75)
- d10: the average shifts from 6(5.5) to 7(7)
- d12: the average shifts from 7(6.5) to 8(8.25)

Given the fact that your DM rules that losing HPs could occur also in situations that normally do not cause damage, this does not look unbalancing at all.

#### Mathematical details.

This section is devoted to justify the above results.

Recall that for a Hit Die with *n* faces, the suggested value for the HP increment in the PHB is given by \$\frac{n}{2}+1\$.

Consider the case of d6: the proposed formula provides the following probabilities:

- \$\frac46\$ of getting 4 (since the probability of obtaining 1,2,3 or 4 is 1/6 for each outcome, that is mapped to 4)
- \$\frac16\$ of getting 5
- \$\frac16\$ of getting 6

Using the formula for the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Random_variables_with_countably_many_outcomes), the average HP per level is
$$
\frac46 4 + \frac16 5 +\frac16 6 = \frac{16+5+6}{6} = 4.5
$$

which can be approximated to 5.

For a die with *n* faces, the expected value becomes
$$
{\rm E}[HP_n] = \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)^2 + \sum_{i=\frac n2+2}^n \frac{i}{n},
$$

where the first term accounts for the expected value of the average:
$$
{\rm E}[\text{average}] = P(\text{average}) \cdot \text{average} = \frac{\text{average}}{n} \cdot \text{average} = \frac{\text{average}^2}{n}
$$

and the second for the other values. A more concise formula reads as
$$
{\rm E}[HP_n] = \frac{5n+6}{8}
$$

Answer (score 3):

### It does not.

It's an average of +0 to +1 HP per level.
Weighted average (X^2 + SUM (X+1 ... D) divided by D); where X is the high average and D is the die type.

- For d6, it shifts the average from 4 to 4.5. (16 + 11) / 6
- For d8, the average shifts from 5 to 5.75. (25 + 21) / 8
- For d10, we see a shift from 6 to 7. (36 + 34) / 10
- For d12, the shift is from 7 to 8.25. (49 + 50) / 12

That's a trivial variation, well within the expected variation of CON bonus and normal damage affects.

In the most extreme case of high rolling this house rule is similar to handing out the Toughness feat for free. For a campaign with as much ad hoc damage as you indicate, that tells me that the DM wants your characters to usually survive. Get hammered, regularly, but mostly survive.

Comment: I am sure those values are not correct.

Comment: @Novak Values corrected.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean now: you're taking the baseline in your comparison to be the fixed "average" HP increase, not the average result of rolling the hit die for HP (which, on average, gives you half a point less). It was not clear to me from the OP's phrasing which method they were currently using, and I (perhaps incorrectly) assumed the latter.

Answer (score 2):

#### The advantages in raw HP vary with the hit dice in play and are worse than gaining a feat

This is easily calculated by taking the "standard average" value for each hit die and the percent of time the roll will be that or less (columns 2 and 3 below).  Then the average of the remaining pips and the percent of time that rolls will be greater than the standard average (columns 3 and 4).  1 x 2 + 3 x 4 = new average hp per level (column 5), with column 6 being the average gain in this new method.

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline   & Min (std) & percent & Avg > std & percent & Result Avg & Difference \\ \hline D6 & 4 & 66.66 & 5.5 &  33.33 & 4.5 & .5 \\ \hline D8 & 5 & 62.5 & 7 & 37.5 & 5.75 & .75 \\ \hline D10 & 6 & 60 & 8.5 &  40 & 7 & 1 \\ \hline D12 & 7 & 58.33 & 10 &  41.67 & 8.25 & 1.25 \\ \hline  \end{array}

As we can see, higher hit dice have a larger gain from this method.

Let's compare to the feat *Tough*:  gain +2 hit points per level.  Tough isn't the best feat, but it does get chosen over others in some builds.  But let's assume that is is just as good as other feat choices (a rather bold assumption).  This new method is at best 62.5% as good as tough, with the worst for D6 hit dice being 25% as good. I suggest you would never even notice a ..5 hp/level gain for Wizards and Sorcerers in actual gameplay. One-third of the time you would get 1 or 2 extra HP at level up.  We can discuss that the upside is greater with this new method, but on average the results will be as shown.  The range of values above average would larger than the range below, but there will be more below-average results.

I suggest that the desire to look at standard deviations is a trap.  Standard deviations don't even apply here, the distribution isn't normal.  Maybe if you're a math major you could make sense of the deviations, but I doubt many can, this is beyond the stats class you took in college.  There is no getting around that the averages will be the averages.

For an Excel simulation of 1000 L20 D6 characters ("Wizards"), the 20,000 rolls gave a 4.496 average and the following distribution of L20 HP.  The average L20 HP is 89.75.  It's a strange looking distribution, but everything about it drives to the averages.  10,000 Wizards doing their HP this way will have an average HP of 90.

Interestingly, there are 389 results above 90, but 486 below 90.  So it will be more common to have below-average results, but above-average results have slightly more upside.

[image]

##### In conclusion

I suggest this new roll method is way worse than giving the players a free feat.  Considering that this is a fairly common homebrew option, **I suggest that this is a weak option to improve the power of Player Characters**, though it does help balance Fighters and Barbarians against Casters, if you think such things are important.

Comment: The 1st result on the d6 is wrong: the expected value is 4.5, not 4.33 .

Comment: The 1st row has computational errors, starting in column 4, which has been rounded inappropriately.  The errors compound through that row.  None of the other values in column 4 have been rounded.  Your column 6 appears to be just plain wrong, and I'm not sure why-- I suspect you are trying to difference the rounded values of column 5 with an unseen but unrounded column of inappropriately rounded average values.

Comment: And overall, the laser focus on average values is highly misleading.

Comment: @Eddymage thanks

Comment: @Novak thanks, I think doing anything other than looking at averages is highly misleading

Comment: If you are changing the minimum roll from a 1 to a 4 (for an ordinarily squishy character like a wizard) that affects the accumulation of points in ways that averages do not reflect.

Comment: @Novak maybe you've discovered a new mathematical thing but I'm skeptical.  A wizard get 1 or 2 more HP one-third of the time.  Again, this is the same as the calcs from Great Weapon fighting.  Those damage numbers don't somehow creep above the average.

Comment: I have discovered nothing.  I just know that the old method follows a (by definition symmetric) gaussian distribution and the new method is neither gaussian nor symmetric.

Comment: @Novak: That's indeed correct, although in practice it matters only for the first few levels. After that the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) takes over and [makes the distribution of the sum look very close to gaussian](https://anydice.com/program/2f142/graph), even though the individual rolls aren't.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen note the VASTLY LONGER right-side tails on those plots.  Contemplate what that means for the mininum values on the old method and the minimum values on the new method.

Comment: The plot is not very convincing: for the same case but with 1e6 simulations (1 million of wizards at level 20) I obtain a distribution very close to the Normal one.

Comment: @Eddymage that's what we would expect from the Central Limit Theorem

Answer (score 2):

Taking more damage than "normal" may balance out having more total HP from a generous method of rolling hit dice on level up.

But if you don't similarly buff healing rolls, **healing (and temp HP buffs) become weaker *relative* to the inflated HP pools**, and relative to damage taken during an adventuring day.  This includes short-rest healing rolling hit dice: rolling all your hit dice often won't get you from 1 HP back to full.

It's not a huge effect, but could lead to an extra spell slot for Prayer of Healing on some adventuring days.  (Or worse if you don't have access to such efficient healing spells.)

OTOH, it could mean you didn't need to heal during some combats where everyone started at full, so more of your spell slots spent on healing can be on efficient heals like PoH (6x `(spell level)d8 + Wis`) instead of expensive in-combat heals like Healing Word.  So either you save spell slots, or your damage output increases because you could do more than a cantrip for damage, or you could cast control / debuff spells instead.

---

Of course, having a larger pool of HP is definitely more survivable.  And it sounds like your DM is inclined to roll damage for stuff some DMs wouldn't, regardless of party HP.  So it's not like you have the option of dropping both of these effects.

If the "excess" damage is mostly incidental and outside combat, then you might still go into combats at full HP and get the full benefits.  Or if you're often down some HP because it wasn't worth it to spend healing resources on a small amount of damage, then maybe you're starting combats with current HP totals closer to what you'd have with standard level-up HP methods, but with some headroom to heal without over-healing.

Comment: Hmm, does this also apply when a feat grants additional HP? I never really thought increasing my pool would be unbalanced with the healing.

Comment: @NautArch: Yeah, for example Tough increases max HP by 2 per level, vs. an ASI to increase your Con mod giving 1/level.  But the Con boost increases your short-rest healing, too.  Things that reduce your damage taken (like more dex for higher AC, and saving-throw boosts) make the same amount of healing go farther.  But sometimes you get unlucky and take a string of hits, so there's no substitute for more HP.  If most of your healing comes from long rests, Tough is great.  If your table has long adventuring days with lots of healing between combats, Tough is still nice but costs more healing.